# How to hide modal after processing is done on page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web page that contains a button. When the button is clicked it calls some code in my code behind that processes. I want to display a "processing" message and a modal to make it so the user has to wait for the processing to be done before they do anything else. I use a javascript function to show the "processing" message and the modal when the button is clicked. When the processing is done the message goes away but the modal stays.

Here's my code:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function ShowProgress2() {
       setTimeout(function () {
    var modal = $('<div />');
    modal.addClass("modal2");
    $('body').append(modal);
    var loading2 = $(".loading2");
    loading2.show();
    var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading2[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
    var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading2[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
    loading2.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);  
   //$('modal2').modal('hide'); //this does not hide the modal when processing is done
   //document.getElementById('modal2').style.display = 'none'; //this does not hide the modal when processing is done
  }
 </script>
```

```css
.modal2
  {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: black;
   z-index: 99;
   opacity: 0.8;
   filter: alpha(opacity=80);
   -moz-opacity: 0.8;
   min-height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
  }
  .loading2
  {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 10pt;
   border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   display: none;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: White;
   z-index: 999;
  }
```

```html
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="MedicaidDataGenerateBillingFile_Generate" Text="Generate" width="100px" OnClientClick="ShowProgress2();"/>

 <div class="loading2" align="center" style="display:none;">
  <div style="margin: auto; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 9998; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #fff; filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7;">
   <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/activity/roller.gif" /><br />
    Generating Billing File...
  </div>
 </div>
```

Running this as is when the button is clicked the modal displays and the processing message displays in the middle of the modal. When the processing is finished the processing message goes away but the modal stays visible. I've tried a couple of things that are listed at the end of the javascript function that I have commented out, neither of them work to hide the modal. I need the code to make it so the modal goes away/is hidden at the same time the processing message goes away. If anyone would help me out with what needs to be changed/added to my code to accomplish this I would be grateful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some additional looking into this I found a solution to getting the modal to hide/go away. I found this bit of code in another page where the similar code is being used and the modal is hidden after the processing is done:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID ="MedicaidDataGenerateBillingFile_Generate" />
</Triggers>
```

I included this code in my code and set the `ControlID` equal to my button ID that is getting clicked and now when the processing is finished the processing message goes away and so does the modal.

I hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

You define modal like this:

```
var modal = $('<div />');
modal.addClass("modal2");
$('body').append(modal); 

document.getElementById('modal2').style.display = 'none';
```

this doesnt work, bc you modal doesn't have any id property, when you created it, only class. Either assign it, or use the class

```
$('modal2').modal('hide');
```

It doesn't work, because the class in jQuery should be written with dot $('.modal2');
And if you are not using any plugins for modals, the code should be

```
$('.modal2').hide();
```

Comment: if I change the references from `modal2` to `.modal2` then the modal doesn't even display at all. Regardless, using `$('.modal2').hide();` or `$('modal2').hide();` does not work, the modal still shows after the processing finishes.

Comment: No, you need to initialize the modal as you did. modal.addClass("modal2"); then use $('.modal2').hide()

Comment: Are there any other classes/styles affecting this modal?